# Can the subgroup membership problem still be hard in known order subgroup?

Tags: elliptic-curves

For example: Given an elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{Z}_q$, and $\#E(\mathbb{F}_q) = p^2$, where $p$ is a prime. Now given a subgroup $\langle G \rangle$ of $E$, and the order of the subgroup $\langle G \rangle$ is $p$. If we randomly sample group element $P$ on $E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ and find that $[p]P=\mathcal{O}$. Can I conclude that $P\in \langle G \rangle$? I want to stress that there may be two subgroups whose orders are both $p$.

Generally, is the subgroup membership problem possible to be hard even the orders of its subgroups are all known?

Comment: By Lagrange Theorem, you can conclude that $P\in \langle G \rangle$,

Comment: But aren't there two groups whose orders are both $p$?(According to a theorem: $E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is isomorphic to one finite cyclic group or two finite cyclic subgroups.) So isn't here $E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ isomorphic to $<G> \bigoplus <G'>$, where the order of $<G'>$ is also $p$? Then $P$ is also possible to falls in $<G'>$

Comment: So what are the subgroup when it is isomorphic to product of two groups?

Comment: I just do not explicitly understand this. I mean, what if there are at least two subgroups whose orders are the same(here we assume the order is $p$). Then the $P$ is also likely to fall in the other subgroup with the same order. In this case, the subgroup membership problem is still hard. Is it reasonable? The main goal for me is to know if the subgroup membership problem is possible to be hard even the order of its subgroups are all known.

Comment: If there are two different subgroups of the same order then $[p]G$ will not help. You can enrich your question with these.

Comment: As far as I can tell [p]P=O guarantees that P is in a subgroup whose order is some factor of p: is $p$ stated to be prime? I don't think it alone guarantees that P is in a particular subgroup of order p

Comment: Yes, it is a prime